# sencha app build package gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I use sencha architect to build an app.

Then I copy the project files such as app, packages, resources, touch, app.js, index,html to a empty app built by sencha cmd. Then I use sencha app build package to build a package, but the error comes. The cmd window are as the follow picture, can anyone help me?

I use win7+sencha cmd4.0+cordova+touch-2.4.1

[image: i use "sencha app build package" and the result is as the pic]

Comment: I don't know if you wanted to put in more pictures but you have linked to only 1 picture, I've corrected it so that the picture displays. What is this line for `i use "sencha app build package" and the result is as the pic` ?

Comment: i ask the question the first time on stackoverflow,, i dont knnow much about the rules,,,i dont know whats the words under the picture for,,

Comment: I see. Currently you don't have enough privilege to put a picture. Someone (like me) will review the question and allow the picture. You tried to add the picture 10 times right?

Comment: i tried several times, its really a hard memory using sencha touch to build app, especially my mother tongue isn't english

Comment: do you know how to fix it??

Comment: No, I don't know how to fix it. I have no clue about java. I just made your question better so that people would hopefully answer it. I'm going to put a points bounty and see if it helps you out. [Read this to know about bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) When people ask you about your issue will you be available to make your situation or issue more clearer?